# Asp Repeater Newline in constant error

Tags: asp.net, .net

Hi I'm trying to use a conditional state inside `<asp:Repeater>` but I'm getting a Newline in constant error. The error is inside the `<ItemTemplate>`

Code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Slides") %>'>
     <ItemTemplate>  
         <%# Eval("SlideId") == "one" ? "<span class='slide-option selected' id='slide-option-<%# Eval("SlideId")%>'></span>" : "<span class='slide-option' id='slide-option-<%# Eval("SlideId")%>'></span>" %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Maybe I'm blind but I don't see any missing character. Or Is there a better way of using a conditional statement in this?

Comment: You can't nest <%# ... %> tags.

Comment: What do you mean? the one inside the span tags?

Comment: Yes.  You have a `<%# ... %>` inside of another which throws off the parser.

Comment: Well I was following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9290349/2104127 which has the tag nested inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```cs
<%# string.Format("<span class='slide-option{0}' id='slide-option-{1}'></span>", Eval("SlideId").ToString() == "one" ? " selected" : "", Eval("SlideId")) %>
```

Comment: This works. I edit out your answer answer to include the `.ToString()` method. Thank You!